# Replace the content of container with data from another container

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, move-semantics

The design of the code is something like that:

```
std::list<std::string> core_data;
...<filling this list up during the application workflow
....


while (<some condition>) {
    std::list<std::string> temp_data;
    //... <some logic to build temp_data 
    // ... based on the elements from core_data 
    // ...
    // replace core_data with temp_data for next iteration
    // in this point core_data is already empty
    core_data = temp_data;
}
```

What is a mostly effective way to assign core_data with temp_data?

Is this way correct? More effective?

```
core_data = std::move(temp_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Say `core_data.swap(temp_data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `core_data = std::move(temp_data);` is much more efficient (`O(1)`) than `core_data = temp_data` (`O(temp_data.size()`). Use it if you don't care about contents of `temp_data` after the assignment.

While move assignment is very likely to be implemented via `swap` as was correctly pointed out by Toby Speight in comments, anyway it's more expressive: the reader of the code doesn't have to guess why you swapped the contents and how `temp_data` is further used in the code.

Comment: do I understand this right - list::swap does the same but into both sides?

Comment: @amigo421 yes, so technically it's doing a bit more work.

Comment: The natural implementation of the move-constructor is in terms of `std::swap`, so you're unlikely to see a performance difference.

Comment: @TobySpeight true. But anyway, I think `core_data = std::move(temp_data)` is more expressive than `swap`.